# MainActivity error while importing package: `react-native-google-vr-panorama`

Tags: react-native

I am getting an error when I import a package into my JS file:

```
import GoogleVRPanorama, { PanoramaView } from 'react-native-google-vr-panorama'
```

Error:

[image: error]

This error I get with all the VR 360 components I try to import.

Edit-1:
I did follow the installation steps but I didn't rebuild the app

> MainApplication.java: [MainApplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLjON.jpg)
>
> So when I rebuild the app, getting the following error:
> C:\Users\cherry\Test03\node_modules\react-native-google-vr-panorama\android\src\main\java\com\xebia\googlevrpanorama\RNGoogleVRPanoramaPackage.java:14:
> error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
> @Override
> ^ Note: C:\Users\cherry\Test03\node_modules\react-native-google-vr-panorama\android\src\main\java\com\xebia\googlevrpanorama\RNGoogleVRPanoramaView.java
> uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:unchecked for details. 1 error :react-native-google-vr-panorama:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-google-vr-panorama:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Due to your error image, it seems the error is related to the `GoogleVRPanoramaManager` object, but you never import this object. Are you sure it's not required to import it?

Comment: I have installed installed the requires packages for this but still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you either 
1. Did not finish the install steps, i.e. adding lines to MainApplication etc., see https://github.com/XebiaStudio/react-native-google-vr-panorama/blob/master/README.md#installation  for details
or 
2. Did not rebuild the app with `react-native run-android`.